# Repeated Measures ANOVA in R Trouble for LARGE Dataset

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I am struggling to determine if using a repeated measures ANOVA for my data is the best analysis, and unfortunately my adviser has not been much help.  I measured luminosity of various fungal isolates at 14, 23, and 32 days post inoculation.  Isolates were generated from five different parental sets: bright72, bright88, intermediate, dim95, and dim 102.  I've formatted the data for R as follows (long-format?):

```
subj    dpi    rlu_s  parent
1      14      235     bright72
2      14      4314    bright72
1      23      2350    bright72
2      23      24555   bright72
1      32      747647  bright72
2      32      373627  bright72
3      14      235     dim95
4      14      4314    dim95
3      23      2350    dim95
4      23      24555   dim95
3      32      747647  dim95
4      32      373627  dim95
```

etc. for a very large data set: 242 total isolates with measurements from the 3 days and my five parental groups

My adviser would like me to run a repeated measures ANOVA, but I'm not interested in a comparison of the luminescence change of a single isolate from 14-->23-->32dpi bc I know that at 14 dpi they are much more dim than at 23 or 32.  I'm more concerned with whether the bright72 are significantly brighter than the dim95, etc.  but have no idea how to approach this analysis as someone with a single biostatistics course down and limited coding knowledge.

I've tried:

`lum_res = aov(formula = rlu_s~ dpi + Error(subj/dpi), data = lumrlu)`

but this does not provide a Mauchly's Sphericity test.

I've also tried:

```
model=ezANOVA(lumrlu, rlu_s, subject, within=dpi, detailed = TRUE, return_aov=TRUE)
```

Which again does not provide Mauchly's (based on the extreme change in measurements from 14 to 32 dpi, I believe I will need to transform my data).

Any help in very simple terms would be greatly appreciated.  I have `car`, `ez`, and `lsr` already installed in R.

Comment: Can you explain what your variables are, what you are attempting to achieve with each of your models, and what your scientific question is? Some of these are hard to figure out based on what you've stated.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I need to use repeated measures at all...  My dependent variable is my luminescence measurement (rlu_s) and my independent variable should be the parental isolate treatment (bright, int, dim).  I have rlu_s time point measurements (14, 23, & 32 dpi) for ~250 different isolates (100 bright, 50 int, 100 dim).  I am trying to determine if isolates that were generated from bright parents are statistically brighter than those generated from intermediate and those generated from dim.  However, because of the time point measurements, things have become complex.

Comment: Isolates are independent of the treatment.  So isolate 1 may be from the bright treatment and measured at 14,23, and 32 dpi, but can not be included in the int, or dim treatments.  I'm so confused.  Every time I speak with my adviser it becomes more confusing

Comment: To reiterate: I suggest stepping back from the stats for a bit and figuring out what your scientific question is. We can advise you on the former but not the latter.

Comment: My scientific question is: will haploid isolates generated from a cross between isolates with a bright bioluminescent phenotype be statistically brighter than haploid isolates generated from a cross between isolates with dim bioluminescent phenotype?

Comment: Looking at the data, with no statistical analysis whatsoever, I can see that the frequency of bright isolates in the bright group is higher than the frequency of bright isolates in the dim group.  However, the parental phenotype does not impact the magnitude of those bright isolates, just the frequency.  I just have a massive data set with measurements collected from multiple time points, and don't know what to do with it

Comment: If you don't mind my asking: why measure at 3 time points if time is not in any way part of your scientific question? What I'm trying to get at is: do you have some implicit hypothesis about changes through time that I (and perhaps other readers) have not understood?

Comment: That's why I'm struggling so much with my adviser on this.  I just happened to monitor their growth from 14-32 days after they were inoculated to the plate.  I KNOW (does not require statistics) that isolates will not be as bright on day 14 as they are on day 32 because they are so much smaller and are focused on primary metabolic functions.  I suggested using only data from 32 dpi, but she is dead set on analyzing measurements from 14, 23, ad 32 dpi.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have a rather messy situation, I'm afraid. First off, your main variable of interest is *parental isolate treatment*, though it is not in your data frame up there. So the most basic version of this model would be **lm(luminescence ~ treatment)**

Comment: But you have to account for variance explainable by 1) parental sets (isolate nested within parental isolate) and 2) time. You have only 5 parental sets, with 2 being bright, 1 intermediate, and 2 dim. The low level of replication at this level makes it hard-to-impossible to deal with using a nested random effect (which would be my inclination). You also have temporal structure that you can account for, but again not so many time points that you can do much with it.

Comment: However, none of this points in the direction of a repeated measures ANOVA, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comments above into an answer:

Your situation is rather messy, I'm afraid. First off, your main variable of interest is *parental isolate treatment*, though it is not in your example data frame. The most basic version of this model would be `lm(luminescence ~ treatment)`

But you have to account for variance explainable by 1) *parental sets* (isolate nested within parental isolate) and 2) *time*. You have only 5 parental sets, with 2 being bright, 1 intermediate, and 2 dim. The low level of replication at this level makes it hard-to-impossible to deal with using a nested random effect (which would be my inclination). You also have temporal structure that you can account for, but again not so many time points that you can do much with it.

However, none of this points in the direction of a repeated measures ANOVA, to the best of my knowledge.